What metrics to collect from Cache service to detect performance degradations?
I have a Cache product that reads and writes to its underlying storage. The thing I want to achieve is a metric that displays Read / Write throughput over some time.
I tried to collect a counter of total_symbols / total_latency, but it seems very volatile. I want  to detect performance degradations over time. No conclusions could be made based on charts (see screenshot):

Any thoughts?

If we ignore what can be measured for now, how do you define a performance degradation? For example, how would that manifest for your (end-)users? Once it is known what symptoms to look for, you can think about root causes for those symptoms and how to detect/measure those.

@BartvanIngenSchenau In my view, cache throughput is defined as the latency per character extracted or inserted. If this latency increases, for example, by 15% compared to the previous week (on average), it indicates degradation. So if number of characters processed over time is also decreasing - this means degradation. This is why I settled on the total_symbols / total_latency metric. I feel there might be something more that can be aggregated or calculated from these numbers, but I’m not sure what. :(

try dividing the data into cohorts, small medium and big requests, read/write etc

Is this produce something you have made? or are you monitoring an off the shelf solution?

@Ewan Yes, I've developed this product
